# How to call a taggued tasks on only one role in a playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a playbook than lauches multiple rôles, one of them manage the install and the uninstall of sophos antivirus. It can handle the installation or the unistallation using tags but musn't obviously do booth a the same time.
So my question is how can I lanch just this role in the playbook with the tag install without overloading all the tasks inside this role? I just want to execute only the taggued task, as the intended use for the tasks in general.

I've tried a few syntax but none seems to work, it always overload all the tasks with the tag instead of executing the taggued tasks:

```
  roles:
    - role: ../roles/repos.linux
    - role: ../roles/sophos
      tags: [install,check]

or   roles:
    - role: ../roles/repos.linux
    - {role: ../roles/sophos, tags: install,check}
```

**Expected:**

> The role execute only the taggued tasks called

**Actual:**

> Every task is overloaded with the tags I try to execute

Answer (score 0):

Use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role). For example:

```
tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: repos.linux
      apply:
        tags:
          - install
          - check
```